# How to add refs to an array in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to store a ref in each elements of my arrays.
Can I insert it direcrly in my array (modifying it) ?

```
    const item = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Text1",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Text2",
  },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You should use a `callback` to get multiple refs and store them in either a `state` or just a `ref`. Something like this

```
const Comp = (props) => {
 const refs = useRef([]);

 return <>
   {props.items.map(i => <div
     key={i}
     ref={el => refs[i] = el}
    >
    {i}
    </div>)
   }
 </>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a "(" before the ">" that should not be here

Comment: I got an issue with the ref[i] : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'MutableRefObject<TextInput>'. Any idea why?